# How can write following query with out isnull() function and with case statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

```
   --Query#1
    declare @npi varchar(10) =null
    declare @IsGpro bit=1
    select  
    *
    from
    tbl_IA_Users I
    where I.CMSYear=2019
    and isnull(I.NPI,'') = case when @IsGpro =1   then '' else @npi end
```

The above query(Query#1) working fine, but i don't need use the isnull() function and  i have writen query as:

```
    --Query#2
    declare @npi varchar(10) =null
    declare @IsGpro bit=1
    select  
    *
    from
    tbl_IA_Users I
    where I.CMSYear=2019
    and I.NPI= case when @IsGpro =1   then null else @npi end
```

But the second query is not working and I don't get any results. How can write the query(Query#1) without the isnull() function ?

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE I.CMSYear = 2019
AND 
(
    (@IsGpro = 1 AND I.NPI is null) OR
    (@IsGpro = 0 AND I.NPI = @npi)
)
```